# C# & operator clarification

Tags: c#, .net, logic

I saw a couple of questions here about the diference between && and & operators in C#, but I am still confused how it is used, and what outcome results in different situations. For example I just glimpsed the following code in a project

```
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt & 1);
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt & 2);
```

When it will result 0 and when >0? What is the logic behind this operator? What are the diferences between the operator '|'?

```
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt | 1);
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt | 2);
```

Can we use the &&, || operators and get the same results (possibly with different code)?

Comment: The second set of `bMyBoolean`s trivially evaluate to true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ampersand does bitwise AND on the integers in their binary representations.
The pipe does bitwise OR.

See here what those bitwise operations mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 11):

The `&&` is a conditional and used in `if` statements and `while`

```
if(x>1 && y<3)
```

this means that x should be greater than 1 and y less than 3, satisfy both conditions

```
if(x>1 || y<3)
```

satisfy one of them

However, & and | are bitwise AND and OR respectively.
ex:

```
 1 | 0  => 1
 1 & 0  => 0
 1 & 1  => 1
```

if this apply for straight integers, their corresponding binary value will be calculated and applied

```
2&1
=>   10  // the binary value of 2
     &
     01  // the binary value of 1
     --
     00  // the result is zero
```

Comment: I think this doesn't explain the difference well. What happens when you use `&` on booleans? What happens when you use `&&` on integers?

Comment: If anyone wants to know why `10 & 01 == 00`, you may understand how bitwase operations are done [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Answer (score 4):

& and | is bit operations. You must use it on bit masks. && and || is logical operations so you can use it for only bool values.

Example of bit operation:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = a|b;
```

in binary format this means a = 00000001, b = 00000010
c = 00000011

So if you use bitmask c it will pass values 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

One more difference is that & operator computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands, if operands are not bool (integer in your case)

Answer (score 2):

`& operator is BItwise AND` operator,it does manipulation on bits.
e.g.  5 & 3

```
        0101    //5
        0011   //3
    ----------
5&3=    0001   //1
```

`| operator is BItwise OR` operator,it does manipulation on bits.
5|3

```
        0101    //5
        0011   //3
    ----------
  5|3=  0111   //7
```

`&&` operator is `logical AND  operator`- it `returns true if all conditions are true`  
e.g.

```
       if((3>5)&&(3>4))   //returns true
       if((6>5)&&(3>4))   //returns false
```

`||` operator is `logical  OR operator`- it `returns true if one of the  conditions is true`
e.g.

```
   if((3>5)||(3>4))   //returns true
   if((6>5)||(3>4))   //returns true
   if((6>5)||(5>4))   //returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers explains for you the different between && and &, so assume you understand this. In here, I just try to explain your specified case.

First case

```
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt & 1);
```

`bMyBoolean` `false` when `nMyInt = 0` because:

```
  00 
& 01 
= 00;
```

Second case:

```
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt & 2);
```

`bMyBoolean` `false` when `nMyInt = 0` or `1` because

```
  00 
& 10 
= 00;
```

Or:

```
  01 
& 10 
= 00;
```

The third and fourth cases with bitwise | are trivial because bMyBoolean always true with any nMyInt

```
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt | 1);
bMyBoolean = Convert.ToBoolean(nMyInt | 2);
```

You cannot apply && or || in this case because they are constraint only for `bool`, you will compiled errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something interesting for  **&** . bit-wise as & be, it can be used
to bool as in example below.

```
bool result = true;
result &= false;
Console.WriteLine("result = true & false => {0}", result );
//result = true & false => False

result = false;
result &= false;
Console.WriteLine("result = false & false => {0}", result );
//result = false & false => False


result = true;
result &= true;
Console.WriteLine("result = true & true => {0}", result );
//result = true & true => True
```