# How does Unary Operator '&' work

Tags: c#

How does the unary operator '&' work ?

In a test project i ran this code:

```
int num = 50, num2 = 100;

int x = num & num2;
```

result: x = 32

```
 int num = 100, num2 = 90;

 int x = num & num2;
```

result :x = 64

How is this calculated ?

Comment: It's not a unary operator.  As for what it does, read up on _bitwise operations_.

Comment: Doing a simple google search should give you the answer and its not a unary operator its a bitwise AND

Comment: The `&` operator takes two operands. Why are you calling it a unary one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# & operator clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600062/c-sharp-operator-clarification)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the bitwise AND Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427585/understanding-the-bitwise-and-operator)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/sbf85k1c.aspx I got the Unary From the MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx):

> Binary & operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, & computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands.
>   For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its operands; that
>   is, the result is true if and only if both its operands are true.

In your case it is integeral type version.

So:

```
 50 in binary is 00110010     
100 in binary is 01100100     
AND result is    00100000 (32 dec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operator works on bits and perform bit-by-bit operation.

Binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands.

```
(A & B) = 12, i.e., 0000 1100
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing: `&` in this context is a *binary* operator, as it has *two* arguments. It is **not** a *unary* operator.

`&` with two arguments is the bitwise AND operator.

`50 & 100` is `0b110010 & 0b1100100`. Apply `&` to each bit gives you `0b100000` which is 32.

You can analyse `100 & 90` similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Binary values

```
50 (10 ) = 0110010  (2)
100 (10) = 1100100  (2)
```

And a logical AND is used so only the bits where both values are 1 are now one resulting in:

```
0100000 (2) = 32 (10)
```

and

```
100 (10) = 1100100  (2)
AND
90 (10) =  1011010 (2)
------------------------
64 (10) =  1000000(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Represent both numbers as binaries (in order to see *bits* clearly when doing *bitwise* operations) and have a look at what's going on:

```
private static String AndExplanation(int left, int right) {
  String x = Convert.ToString(left, 2);
  String y = Convert.ToString(right, 2);
  String z = Convert.ToString(left & right, 2);

  int length = Math.Max(x.Length, y.Length);

  return String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    $"{x.PadLeft(length, '0')} ({left}) &",
    $"{y.PadLeft(length, '0')} ({right})",
    new String('-', length),
    $"{z.PadLeft(length, '0')} ({left & right})"
  );
}
```

Tests

```
Console.Write(AndExplanation(50, 100));

Console.Write(AndExplanation(90, 100));
```

You'll see:

```
0110010 (50) &
1100100 (100)
-------
0100000 (32)
```

and

```
1011010 (90) &
1100100 (100)
-------
1000000 (64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is - it depends.

For integers, as in your case it does bit operations. So `01100100` (100) **bitwise AND** `00110010` (50) = `00100000` (32).

For booleans that's an eager AND (evaluates both expressions always) - unlike the lazy AND `&&` which doesn't evaluate the second expression if first is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bitwise AND:

In "0b0110010 AND 0b1100100", you should look for the the 1's and 0's shared at common places, which gives you 0b0100000=32.

The same holds for "100 AND 90" which gives you 0b1000000=64.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bits operator **and**. The bits(binary) for 50 is 110010 and 100 is 1100100, when you align them (flush to the right), you get

 `110010
1100100`

The & operator works in such a way that, at each position, you get 1 if both lines have 1 and you get 0 otherwise, as shown below.

 `110010
1100100
|||||||
0100000`

So you get the binary result 100000, which is 32.